# Turning a regular expression into a dreamweaver command

Tags: regex, dreamweaver

I have a regular expression which works in Dreamweaver's find and replace but when I create a dreamweaver command it doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

```
function canAcceptCommand() {
return true;
}

function commandButtons() {
return new Array("Go!", "doIt()", "Cancel", "window.close()");
}

function doIt() {

dreamweaver.setUpFindReplace({
    searchString: "([0-9]{1}[\.\s][\s\D]?[^<]*?)(\£\d\.\d\d[^<])",
    replaceString: "<strong>$1$2</strong>",
    searchWhat: "document",
    searchSource: true,
    useRegularExpressions: true
}); 
dreamweaver.replaceAll();   

window.close();
}
```

Thanks

PS - Thanks to sniffer for helping with the regular expression

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I've fixed the issue. It looks like it didn't like the \d, \D or \s and was reading them as letters so I reverted to the long hand way of doing it [0-9] instead of \d etc.

Now it work fine.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remember that your Dreamweaver command is written in JavaScript, which reserves the backslash character as an escape in strings. Since your search string is technically just a JavaScript string, you need to escape the backslashes in your regular expression.

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strings.asp

So your search string should work like this:

```
searchString: "([0-9]{1}[\\.\\s][\\s\\D]?[^<]*?)(\\£\\d\\.\\d\\d[^<])"
```

If you are planning on running multiple find and replaces within the same Dreamweaver command, you may want to consider making the find and replace a function that you can call multiple times.

Example:

```
function doIt() {
    function findReplace(a,b) {
        dreamweaver.setUpFindReplace({  
            searchString: a,  
            replaceString: b,  
            searchWhat: "document", // Or "allOpenDocuments" 
            searchSource: true,  
            useRegularExpressions: true
        });  
        dreamweaver.replaceAll();
    }
    // Call your find and replaces like this
    // findReplace("find string", "replace string")
    findReplace("([0-9]{1}[\\.\\s][\\s\\D]?[^<]*?)(\\£\\d\\.\\d\\d[^<])", "<strong>$1$2</strong>"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried it with?

```
dreamweaver.setUpFindReplace({
    searchString: "/([0-9][\.\s][\s\D]?[^<]*?)(\£[0-9]\.[0-9][0-9][^<])/",
    ...
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Still not working with adding the /

Comment: I just don't understand why it works in the find and replace box but not as a command.

Comment: another approach would be `searchString: /([0-9]{1}[\.\s][\s\D]?[^<]*?)(\£\d\.\d\d[^<])/`  (without the quotes)

Comment: Still not having any joy using the expression with \d, but I got it working buy using [0-9] instead of the \d